# Spring cloud gateway low throughput with security

Tags: spring-security, performance-testing, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to secure my `spring cloud gateway` with basic auth. But I found out that when I add `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency and basic configuration, the gateway has poor throughput on performance test.

- with security - 53.2/sec
- without security - 694.1/sec

What is wrong?

pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.11.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-gateway</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <name>demo-gateway</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR11</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
                <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.8</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>5.7.1</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

security config

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityWebFluxConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService authentication() {
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are observing this because Spring Security leverages an adaptive one-way function to store the password. These are intentionally resource intensive, which means validating a username and password for every request will degrade performance of an application significantly.
There is nothing Spring Security (or any other library) can do to speed up the validation of the password since security is gained by making the validation resource intensive.

Rather than using HTTP Basic Authentication, I encourage you to exchange the long term credentials (i.e. username and password) for a short term credential (i.e. session, OAuth Token, etc).
The short term credential can be validated quickly without any loss in security.

There is an in-depth explanation of this in the [Password Storage section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html) of the Spring Security reference documentation.

Comment: The link is now broken